# Exception in ServletContextListener and its impact

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

In our web application we need some information from a list of web services. Once we get that information, we put that in `Application Context`. We are invoking those web services at the application startup using a `ServletContextListener`.

Let us assume that the web service is down due to some reason and `ServletContextListner` gives some `ConnectionTimeOutException`.

Will that affect the initialization of all the servlets in the application?

Which is the best place to keep this? `Servlet` or `ServletContextListener`? We can put this information in `init()` method of a servlet and set the `load-startup-value` as a positive number.

Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like the most robust solution. You're building a start-up dependency into the heart of your service. I think you're better off building that initialisation into the app such that it doesn't have to succeed (or even run?) upon startup, and will fail gracefully.

Ideally you should be able to retry that initialisation request (perhaps lazt instantiation and/or via a user request) such that your service is recovery-oriented and can retain some functionality in the face of downstream failures.

Comment: Thanks Brian. So you mean to say it is better to put this logic in the init method of a servlet? Should I load this servlet on startup?